# Не работает терминал в VS Code

Tags: консоль, visual-studio-code

При открытии терминала в нем ничего не происходит. Просто висит каретка ввода, причем ввести ничего не получается. Kill terminal не помогает ровно так же, как перезагрузка пк, вс кода и его переустановка. Удаление настроек так же не помогло, мало того, теперь каждый файл открывается не в новой вкладке, а в той же самой. Смена cmd на powershell тоже не помогла.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Изменил терминал на Git Bash, ничего не изменилось, до сих пор терминал не реагирует на ввод.

---

**UPD**: оказалось был включен режим совместимости с Windows 8. Отключил и все заработало.

Comment: Тут что то с windows я думаю

Comment: Попробуйте обновить программу. Посмотрите настройки программы. Установите новые обновления windows. Если результата не будет, то попробуйте переустановить программу полностью

Comment: Была аналогичная проблема, только был установлен режим совместимости с Windows 7.

Comment: 5k просмотров, красава)

Answer (score 0):

Была аналогичная проблема, только был установлен режим совместимости с Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Проблемы с совместимостью ребят. Отключите его из свойства и все заработает. [image: уберите галочку для "Режима совместимости"]

уберите галочку для "Режима совместимости

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]